Are there any strategies around editing dictionaries nested in shared dictionaries?
I'm trying to edit a dictionary inside a shared dictionary in separate processes but they're immutable. Are there any techniques that I might be missing on how to get around this?
Here's an example
import multiprocessing

def main():
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    dictionary = manager.dict()

    dictionary["jim"] = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z' : 3}

    print(dictionary['jim'])

    dictionary['jim']['x'] += 1

    print(dictionary['jim'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Sorry, but SO isn't a debugging service.  Cut the code down to a specific problem with a [mcve], document what it is doing vs. what it should do, and [edit] the question to show this.

@Mark Tolonen Done!

Thanks, that's much easier to understand the problem.  In the future explain the output and what was expected as well.  I figured out after running it what the issue was.

yeah, it felt better to clean up my question. I posted it while I had brain fog...

dictionary is a DictProxy object.  Getting an item from that proxy such as dictionary['jim'] returns a copy of the proxied dictionary value; in this case, another dictionary.  Then, dictionary['jim']['x'] modifies that copy and not the shared process memory containing the actual dictionary contents.
To fix, extract a key's value from the ProxyDict, modify it, and assign it back to the same key:
import multiprocessing

def main():
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    dictionary = manager.dict()
    dictionary["jim"] = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z' : 3}
    print(dictionary['jim'])
    d = dictionary['jim']  # extract the value from the DictProxy
    d['x'] += 1            # modify it
    dictionary['jim'] = d  # assign it back
    print(dictionary['jim'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Output:
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
{'x': 2, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}


You can nest a shared dict in the shared dict:
dictionary["jim"] = manager.dict({'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z' : 3})

Demo: https://ideone.com/5jS2SK
Excerpt from the documentation:

Shared objects are capable of being nested. For example, a shared
container object such as a shared list can contain other shared
objects which will all be managed and synchronized by the SyncManager.

